# How to do implement incremental backups in a PostgreSQL container

Tags: database, postgresql, containers, backup, pitr

My requirement is to backup the data in PostgreSQL container, and considering the time-consuming issue, I plan to use WAL for incremental backup.

I don't want to distinguish between primary and backup servers, I only have one server, and I want to move the entire database to another location when needed, such as when I need to change the server address, etc.

The modifications made to the postgresql.conf data are as follows:

```
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'test ! -f /mnt/server/archivedir/%f && cp %p /mnt/server/archivedir/%f'
```

And two scripts have been written outside, the first is the basebackup script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONTAINER_NAME="timescaledb"
DB_USER="postgres"
temp_folder="/tmp/pgdata/backup"
BackupFolder="/home/user/backup"
timestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d)

docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME pg_basebackup -U postgres --checkpoint=fast -Ft -z -P -D $temp_folder
docker cp $CONTAINER_NAME:$temp_folder $BackupFolder/postgres_backup_$timestamp/
docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME rm -rf $temp_folder
```

The second script is the restore script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONTAINER_NAME="timescaledb"
temp_folder="/tmp/pgdata/backup"
timestamp=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
postgres_backup_path="/home/user/TimeScaleDB/timescaledb_data"
folder_name="/home/user/backup/postgres_backup_20230502"

docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME chmod -R 777 /mnt

docker stop $CONTAINER_NAME

sudo chmod -R 777 ${postgres_backup_path}

rm -rf ${postgres_backup_path}/*

mkdir -p ${postgres_backup_path}

tar -xf ${folder_name}/base.tar.gz -C ${postgres_backup_path}/

echo restore_command = 'cp /mnt/server/archivedir/%f %p' >> ${postgres_backup_path}/postgresql.auto.conf

echo recovery_target_time = '${timestamp}' >> ${postgres_backup_path}/postgresql.auto.conf

touch $postgres_backup_path/standby.signal

docker start $CONTAINER_NAME

until docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME pg_isready; do
sleep 1
done

docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME psql -U postgres -c "select pg_wal_replay_resume();"
```

I don't need to specify the time point to recover to, I just need to recover all records. However, I still cannot succeed, and I would like to ask what the correct way to do this.

Under this restore script, the problem I encountered is that it always tells me that a certain file does not exist, but I should not have this file in my folder, and I don't know why it is asking for this file to be restored.

The files in /mnt/server/archivedir are shown in the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTPSb.png)

And the container's logs after I used the restore script as follows:

```
2023-05-02 08:33:32.285 UTC [1] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2023-05-02 08:33:32.287 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-05-02 08:33:32.288 UTC [51] LOG:  shutting down
2023-05-02 08:33:32.323 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
2023-05-02 08:33:33.284 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.2.1_pre1) 10.2.1 20201203, 64-bit
2023-05-02 08:33:33.284 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-05-02 08:33:33.284 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-05-02 08:33:33.289 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-05-02 08:33:33.336 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2023-05-02 05:56:02 UTC
2023-05-02 08:33:33.454 UTC [28] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2023-05-02 08:33:33.704 UTC [21] LOG:  restored log file "00000002.history" from archive
2023-05-02 08:33:33.704 UTC [21] LOG:  restored log file "00000003.history" from archive
2023-05-02 08:33:33.705 UTC [21] LOG:  restored log file "00000004.history" from archive
2023-05-02 08:33:33.706 UTC [21] LOG:  restored log file "00000005.history" from archive
2023-05-02 08:33:33.706 UTC [21] LOG:  restored log file "00000006.history" from archive
2023-05-02 08:33:33.707 UTC [21] LOG:  restored log file "00000007.history" from archive
2023-05-02 08:33:33.708 UTC [21] LOG:  restored log file "00000008.history" from archive
2023-05-02 08:33:33.709 UTC [21] LOG:  restored log file "00000009.history" from archive
2023-05-02 08:33:33.710 UTC [21] LOG:  restored log file "0000000A.history" from archive
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000B.history': No such file or directory
2023-05-02 08:33:33.711 UTC [21] LOG:  entering standby mode
2023-05-02 08:33:33.712 UTC [21] LOG:  restored log file "0000000A.history" from archive
2023-05-02 08:33:33.723 UTC [21] LOG:  restored log file "0000000A0000000000000003" from archive
2023-05-02 08:33:33.737 UTC [21] LOG:  restored log file "00000002.history" from archive
2023-05-02 08:33:33.740 UTC [21] LOG:  restored log file "00000003.history" from archive
2023-05-02 08:33:33.745 UTC [21] LOG:  restored log file "00000004.history" from archive
2023-05-02 08:33:33.749 UTC [21] LOG:  restored log file "00000005.history" from archive
2023-05-02 08:33:33.752 UTC [21] LOG:  restored log file "00000006.history" from archive
2023-05-02 08:33:33.755 UTC [21] LOG:  restored log file "00000007.history" from archive
2023-05-02 08:33:33.759 UTC [21] LOG:  restored log file "00000008.history" from archive
2023-05-02 08:33:33.764 UTC [21] LOG:  restored log file "00000009.history" from archive
2023-05-02 08:33:33.771 UTC [21] LOG:  redo starts at 0/3000028
2023-05-02 08:33:33.771 UTC [21] LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/3000100
2023-05-02 08:33:33.772 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000A0000000000000004': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000B.history': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000A0000000000000004': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000B.history': No such file or directory
2023-05-02 08:33:34.655 UTC [62] FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000A0000000000000004': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000B.history': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000A0000000000000004': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000B.history': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000A0000000000000004': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000B.history': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000A0000000000000004': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000B.history': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000A0000000000000004': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000B.history': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000A0000000000000004': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000B.history': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000A0000000000000004': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000B.history': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000A0000000000000004': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000B.history': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000A0000000000000004': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000B.history': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000A0000000000000004': No such file or directory
cp: can't stat '/mnt/server/archivedir/0000000B.history': No such file or directory
```

Comment: You have the instance as a replica by the look of it. It will keep checking for the "next" WAL file every so often expecting the primary to provide it at some point. Check the documentation for how to promote a replica to be a new primary - I'm not sure what the "standard" way is with a docker-based installation and there are several options available.